# Git did not push correctly after rewriting history

Tags: git

My repo is pretty linear

```
c1-->c2-->c3
```

I made a mistake at c2, so I want to go back and fix it, I used

```
git rebase -i c2
```

I made the changes to c2, then

```
git add <whatever-files-changes>
git commit --amend --no-edit
git rebase --continue
```

Lastly, I did a force push

```
git push origin <mybranch> -f
```

I am expecting the following on my remote branch which I just pushed to:

```
c1-->c2+change-->c3
```

However, my remote branch now looks like:

```
c1-->c2-->c3+change
```

What did I do wrong in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `git rebase -i c2` you change your history from `c2` onwards, using `c2` as the base and actually not changing it, so your changes appear in `c3`. If you want to change `c2` try rebasing using `c1` as the new base.